# Error when building vsal project in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I am new to building, compiling projects with cmake/visual studio so please go easy on me ;).

I am trying to configure [VSAL](https://github.com/YuvalNirkin/vsal) lib. I used CMake GUI for configuration and generating (Visual Studio 2015 compiler).

When I build ALL_BUILD in Visual studio I get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: vsal, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_64.lib(value_semantic.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
2>------ Build started: Project: vsal_player, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\vsal.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

One thing that is bothering me, why is CMake using x86_amd64 and not amd64 compiler.

```
Check for working CXX compiler: G:/Programske datoteke (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: G:/Programske datoteke (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
```

Versions:

- Visual Studio Professional 2015
- CMake 3.8.0
- Boost 1.64.0
- vsal 1.0

Thank you for your help !

Comment: In the CMake GUI, try selecting the Generator "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" instead of "Visual Studio 14 2015" or inversely.

Comment: I changed generator from "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" to "Visual Studio 14 2015". I get an error :  
        
`1>------ Build started: Project: vsal, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>opencv_highgui320.lib(opencv_highgui320.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
2>------ Build started: Project: vsal_player, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\vsal.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: I see. If I see it correctly, your Boost library was compiled in 32 bit mode and your OpenCV library in 64 bit mode. The vsal library needs both, which is a problem. I would suggest re-compiling your Boost library in 64 bit mode.

Comment: This is the right solution. All I had to do, was  run `.\b2 address-model=64` command. Thank you so much !

Comment: Great! I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compiling a 64-bit program, but the Boost library you are trying to link against is a 32-bit library.

Recompiling the Boost library in 64-bit mode will solve your problem.